# Request for change of wording: "song" should be "piece"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, site-attributes, help-center

In a few instances, the site's system text uses the term "song" when it really means "piece".

The term "song" technically implies there is at least some component of the music that is to be *sung*.
The more general term for a unit of musical composition is a "piece".

I request that the term "song" be changed to "piece", (or perhaps a hybrid "song/piece").

---

I've found the following instances in the system text, but there may be more:

1. When *voting to close* a question for *A community-specific reason*, the following options are available:

   > o **Basic analysis questions**, such as "What key is this `song` in?" are off-topic. Questions should be substantial and refer to a well-defined work or subsection, including a concrete reference (sheet music, etc.).
   >
   > o Questions about **transcribing or finding** a particular `song`, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers.
2. In the [Help center > Asking](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

   > • identifying a `song`, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique, chord progression, etc.
   >
   > • transcription of specific works, including identifying notes/chords/meters/other elements in `songs`
3. On the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) page:

   > x  Identifying a `song`, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique, chord progression, etc.

Comment: Although technically correct, does it really improve the clarity of the instructions? I would lean toward "no".

Answer (score 2):

While experts and professionals will know the meaning of "piece", those with less music knowledge will far better understand "song" - and we really want to make it easier for them to see that these are off topic, so my view is that while you are correct, I don't think it would improve things, and may end up giving us more off topic questions.